# Structuring AWS Terraform code for multi-region deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have some Terraform managed AWS resources. However I now need to replicate these resources in 2 other regions pretty much 1-to-1. What's the best way of structuring my terraform code so that everything is as concise as possible. My one constraint is that I need to peer the VPCs that I create for my resources (1 VPC for each region). I read that I can't do `count` over provider resources in Terraform. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Why not provide region as input parameter to your script? This way you have only one script version.

Comment: You can try with Terraform Workspace (https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces)